# Trouble with integration of following: $ \int^\infty_0 \exp(a(x)+b(x))a'(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I tried to solve it by partial integration but I am getting similar expression in loop.
I saw similar stuff before that people use gamma function to solve this type of question but I can not handle it now. Someone can please help me?

$\int^\infty_0 \exp(a(x)+b(x))a'(x)dx$

Comment: This won't be possible unless $b(x)$ has something to do with $a(x)$. Indeed, if $a(x)=x$ and $b(x)=\ln f(x)-x$, you're talking about integrating an arbitrary function $f(x)$!

Comment: in case:  a(x)= x^{p},  b(x)=x^{k}, is it still imposibble?

Comment: That example makes the integral diverge to $\infty$.